# Select object via scanner and add it to an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner

so I want to add an already created object to a list selecting it from the console (i dunno if a Scanner works).

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Car c1 = new Car("bmw", 1);
    Car c2 = new Car("mercedes", 1);
    Car c3 = new Car("susuki", 1);

    ArrayList<Car> carList = new ArrayList<>();
    carList.add(c1);
    carList.add(c2);

    //something like this
    Car carToAdd = input.nextCar();
    carList.add(carToAdd);
```

for example I want to add the Car c3 to the ArrayList.
please help and thank you D:

Comment: What do you expect to appear on console and what you user is supposed to input?

Comment: By the way, it's "Suzuki" instead of "Susuki".

Comment: umm i dunno if this makes sense, but here it goes, so c3(suzuki) it's already created and it's not in the arrayList, so i want a "Scanner" to appear in the console where i could write the object name, in this case c3, and then add it to the arrayList :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to display options, and what you want the user to input to the console, you may want to handle different scenarios. The easiest way I can think of is to list all cars available in one Array, and then listen for an index (offset by one, if you'd like). Then use that index to pull the desired car out of the cars Array, and put it into your result Array.

Here's an example. Instead of creating a car class, I just used Strings for simplicity.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
import java.util.ArrayList;
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
       cars.add("chevy");
       cars.add("ford");
       cars.add("weiner-mobile");
       System.out.println("Please select a car");
       for(int i = 0; i<cars.size(); i++){
           System.out.println(String.valueOf(i+1)+" ) " + cars.get(i));
       }
       int reply = scanner.nextInt();
       System.out.println("you chose: " + cars.get(reply-1));
       ArrayList<String> chosenCar = new ArrayList<String>();
       chosenCar.add(cars.get(reply-1));

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Please select a car
1 ) chevy
2 ) ford
3 ) weiner-mobile
> 2
you chose: ford
```

note: you probably want to make sure the input is an index in range, either by surrounding it in a try/catch and handling the indexOutOfRange exception, or checking the index against the length of the Array to ensure it's within range before calling get(i). The `nextInt()` call will throw an exception if the input is not castable to an int